# Receive Firebase Notification with Firebase Token

Tags: php, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can I get firebase notifications without a phone.
I know firebase Instance Id, Firebase Token and Device ID. Cant I receive all notifications  with PHP, node.js etc.
I want pull Firebase Notifications.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging only supports delivery of messages to iOS, Android and Web devices. There are no public APIs/SDKs for delivery to other devices/platforms through Firebase Cloud Messaging.

For the platforms you mention, consider using one of Firebase's databases (Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore) both of which allow delivering of realtime notifications when the data in the database changes.